# Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance unknown host issue

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I have a Tomcat environment running on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (within a VPC). Right of the bet after uploading my tomcat war file, I got

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-1-1-293: ip-10-1-1-293: unknown error.
```

After a bit of research, I found the solution to this is to add a line on my /etc/hosts file, something like so by doing ssh into the ec2 instance:

```
127.0.0.1   ip-10-1-1-293
```

My question is, wouldn't my auto-scaling instances run into the same issue? If so, my environment will auto-scale but there will be no benefit. What will be a right way to set things up?

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify your hostnames if your internal DNS is setup correctly on your VPC. Check your DNS resolution and DNS hostnames are in fact enabled?

Comment: I checked and found both DNS resolution, and DNS hostnames on the VPC are set to 'yes'. What else should I check?

Comment: @Nayan , did you ever find the solution?